# Ruby: Averaging values of Array of Arrays while Grouping according to Date

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

How to average values of the second element of an array of arrays; instead of adding them :

```
[ [ '01-01-2001', 4 ], [ '01-01-2001', 5 ], [ '01-01-2001', 6 ], [ '01-02-2001', 7] ]
```

to

```
[ ['01-01-2001', 5], [ '01-02-2001', 7] ]
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of doing that.

```
arr = [[ '01-01-2001', 4 ], [ '01-01-2001', 5 ], [ '01-01-2001', 6 ], [ '01-02-2001', 7]]
```

**Use [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)**

```
arr.group_by(&:first).transform_values { |v| v.sum(&:last).fdiv(v.size) } 
  #=> {"01-01-2001"=>5.0, "01-02-2001"=>7.0}
```

See [Hash#transform_values](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) and [Numeric#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv).

The initial step is to group the elements by date:

```
arr.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"01-01-2001"=>[["01-01-2001", 4], ["01-01-2001", 5], ["01-01-2001", 6]],
  #    "01-02-2001"=>[["01-02-2001", 7]]}
```

**Use [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-update)**

This way uses the form of `Hash#update` (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged.

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |(k,v), h|
  h.update(k=>[v, 1]) { |_k, (otot, onbr), (ntot, nnbr)| [otot+ntot, onbr+1] }
end.transform_values { |tot, nbr| tot.fdiv(nbr) }
```

See the doc for an explanation of the three block variables used in the block that returns the value of each key that is contained in both hashes being merged. The hash `h` being constructed contains, for each distinct date string, a 2-element array whose first value is a running total of values for the given date and whose second value is the number occurrences of that date. Keeping just the running total of all values is of course more space-efficient than maintaining an array of all values, as done by the `group_by` method.

Note that Ruby permits `h.update(k=>[v, 1])` as shorthand for `h.update({ k=>[v, 1] })`.